# how to put icons on menu_item in android apps?

Tags: android, menu

Why the icons didn't appear when i used the menu.xml below !!. Please help me.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <group android:id="@+id/group1">
    <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Embelance"   android:showAsAction="always|withText"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/E_H1" android:title="To home"  android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/E_W1" android:title="To work"   android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/E_O1" android:title="To oppional"  android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="Fier"  android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/F_H1" android:title="To Home"  android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/F_W1" android:title="To work"   android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/F_O1" android:title="To Optional"  android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

and when used the next attribute it shows that there is error in the app. :  the window
says that the project contains error(s),fix it before the its running or something like that.

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_launcher"
```

and the code is:

```
  @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_context_menu, menu);

}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 


    // .......
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.E_H1:          // ........... 
                           break;
            case...case....case......      // other cases   


        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: What would you expect to appear? You have a group of menu items where the first has no title (so you will have only an icon), the second menu item has nothing and the third is the closest to "something". What are your expectations for this menu?

Comment: @gunar this is just an example not my real menu. i want to appear an icon in the menu_item, for example item called(Fire) and near it an icon resemble fire. what i should do?×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer this, but so far the question is not 100% clear to me. Based on the comments, it seems you wish to know how to combine icons with text in menu item.

For that you have provided the answer yourself in your question: the 3-rd item contains what you need. If you wish to group items in a menu item block, then you can use groups as you did, but specifically for your example, the group is point-less. Something like below will suffice (running on a Motorola Defy 2.3.6 and on Nexus 4):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/context_setting_item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/action_settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

In your `Activity` you will have (suppose menu is in `/res/menu/entry.xml`):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.entry, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.context_setting_item1:
        Toast.makeText(this, "context_setting_item1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Now, to go back to the menu item general discussion: these visual components have been replaced by [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) - it is more friendly, more straight-forward when it comes to expose the content/app-hierarchy and it is sexy! :)

To dive into development, you can check this Android developers blogs, ["Goodbye to MenuItem".](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) For more development details check the [developer section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). From programming perspective it's not that much of big deal as the action bar components are developed with `menu items` in xml. You just need to provide more XML attributes.

Ex.: Only the above xml changes to:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/context_setting_item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="@string/action_settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

And the Activity code remains as it is.

*Note that I have added only `android:showAsAction="always|withText"`.*

The fun part is that nothing changes on Motorola 2.3.6 (since `ActionBar` was added in API level 11), but on Nexus you'll notice the top action bar has the icon on top. Previously, it had a 3-dots and the user had to tap on them in order to view the action.

If you wish to have the action bar in api-level below 11, I strongly recommend using [Sherlock ActionBar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Comment: see my real menu above, there is no icon appear in any menu_item even when tested the app in my phone(GALAXY GRAND 4.1.2) and even when i added your answers to the menu.xml nothing change. please help me i had finish the application but i want it to be more sexy. HELP...

Comment: Can you show the `Activity` code that makes use of this xml? Also, what is the `targetSDK` from Manifest?

Comment: you're not overriding the correct method in `Activity`. Instead of `onCreateOptionsMenu` you're overriding `onCreateContextMenu`. That's a different thing. Please check my answer as I highlighted how to inflate the menu XML.

Comment: sorry, i thought **menu** and **context_menu** are same, yes when `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` used in menu_item the icon **appears**, i wasted your time and i found that **context_menu** don't support icons in their items. thank you for helping me.